# Come back from FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-button

How can I handle the back button in a FragmentPagerAdapter? I'm pressing the back button, but the app is going out of the activity and I only want to go back to the previous fragment.

Comment: just over ride onBackPressed of activity and create interface say handleback button pressed and let fragment implement that back button interface...if you want I can give u sample code.

Comment: please, can you show me your sample code?

Comment: please check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Basically we are going to implement Observer pattern here.

Let have public interface which have one method called backButtonPressed and return boolean true or false

public interface HandleBackButtonHandler
{
    boolean backButtonPressed();
}

We will notify the current fragment that back button has been pressed, Please handle it.

Lets have fragment class as follows

public class fragment extend Fragment implement HandleBackButtonHandler
{
    .......

    public boolean backButtonPressed()
    {
        // Do what ever you want to do when user press back button here

        return true // if you want to handle the back button pressed else return false
    }
    ......
}



Lets override onBackPressed method of your activity where you will attach your fragments

@Override
public final void onBackPressed()
{

    HandleBackButtonHandler handlebackButtonViaFragment  = (HandleBackButtonHandler ) Adapter.getCurrentFragment();  // safely typecast as interface is implemented by fragment
    if (handlebackButtonViaFragment != null && handlebackButtonViaFragment. backButtonPressed())
    {
        return // this mean fragment has handle the back button, activity you don’t need to do any action
        }   
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```